lattice modifier not adjusting correctly on sphere
I have an object I'm trying project onto the sphere, but its deforming when its shrinkwrapped.
Using the lattice I have made the following:





Blend file shared, thank you.

Move the lattice and the object closer to the target position.
Add  some geometry to the parts that need to curve around the sphere.


Thanks so much, I got a good result, never thought that the distance would affect the shrinkwrap.
